# How to register the same DB Context with 2 different connection?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to register the same DB Context with two different connection string in .Net Core?
And, use the any of these 2 contexts based on what is passed in the header.

Thanks!

Comment: Different connection strings?

Comment: yes. we have to 2 DB with same tables and everything. It is just that based on certain parameter, the data has to be sent to different instance. @Schwarzie2478

Comment: I think you need two DB Context for this.  (99% sure)  How would a model stay consistent if it doesn't have all the changes you did?  I don't think this is the best way to separate those insert statement ( what you probably want).  Either do this in your business logic or at database level ( if they can talk to each other)  Trigger, stored procs, view.

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 So you mean i would need 2 context classes , Contextone and contexttwo?
then i register these 2 instance in the startup.

and then in my business layer, i have to inject both these instance and use any one of them based on some parameter.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking too.  It's what you do with different models, but it can be used the same for the same model with different connectionstrings...

Comment: yes, I want to use 1 context but  how do i dependency inject the right context(with connection string) based on the data that is passed in the header @Schwarzie2478

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206351/discussion-between-rocket-singh-and-schwarzie2478).

Comment: _"based on what is passed in the header"_ - do you have a database per customer?

Comment: @RocketSingh what's the *actual* problem? You can easily pass different connection strings to the constructor. DbContexts are supposed to be short-lived so you don't need anything else. DI isn't a concern, just pass the *correct* connection string in the `AddDbContext` based on whatever criteria you use for this - which you haven't explained. You could go as far as creating your own middleware to create DbContexts based on whatever criteria you want.

Comment: @RocketSingh you haven't told us what you *do* want yet - are you trying to implement a multitenant application? There are *many* ways to to that, using either a single database and EF query filters, different databases per tenant, or a combination of shared and isolated databases. Many articles explain how to do that too, like [this one](https://gunnarpeipman.com/presentations/aspnet-core-multitenant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the information you need to decide on which connection string to use is in header, this is simplest solution:

```
// needed below
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

// register DbContext with options that change depending on request's header
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((provider, builder) =>
{
    // get current HttpContext
    HttpContext context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    // get relevant header
    var headerValue = context.Request.Headers["user-agent"].Single();

    // create relevant connection string based on header value and configure context to run against SQL Server
    var connectionString = CreateConnectionString(headerValue);
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really clear, so let's assume the actual problem is accessing a multitenant database. Gunnar Peipman has written [multiple articles](https://gunnarpeipman.com/presentations/aspnet-core-multitenant/) and a presentation on how to implement multi-tenancy in ASP.NET Core, and one specifically for [Database per tenant](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-database-per-tenant/) and [ASP.NET Core Tenant Providers](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-tenant-providers/).

The solution is actually very simple - have the *context* ask for the correct connection through an injected service :

```
public class PlaylistContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Tenant _tenant;

    public DbSet<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

    public PlaylistContext(DbContextOptions<PlaylistContext> options,
                            ITenantProvider tenantProvider)
        : base(options)
    {
        _tenant = tenantProvider.GetTenant();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenant.DatabaseConnectionString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
...
}
```

This moves the problem of tenant detection to `ITenantProvider` through an HTTP header. That's easy to do too - create a class that accesses the HttpContext through an IHttpContextAccessor dependency. This can be as simple as :

```
public class WebTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private Tenant _tenant;

    public WebTenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
                                TenantsContext context)
    {
        var tenantID= accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ThatHeader", out var thatHeaderValue);

        //Load the tenant data eg from database
        _tenant = context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.SomeKey==tenantID);
    }

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {
        return _tenant;
    }
}
```

All that's left is registering all contexts and dependencies. Again, nothing special :

```
services.AddDbContext<TenantsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
services.AddScoped<ITenantProvider, WebTenantProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Hi, what will be 'connection' in startup.cs?
services.AddDbContext<TenantsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

This connection cannot be empty as in the code first approach, add-migration would fail.

Comment: @RocketSingh whatever database you want to use to store the tenant configuration. That's not the important part though - you could use any kind of storage you want to store the tenant data. Are you asking about multitenancy then? You should update the question and make that specific

Comment: Let me try out, what you have suggested. Looking into it now

Answer (score -1):

I've quickly put together this code. Untested, might need some modifications to work. The main point is to not use standard DI registration, but use your own factory to create the context.

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    public DbContext Create(string contextTarget)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        // use contextTarget to create/read the correct connection string here
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blogging;integrated security=True;");
        var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Then register it in Configure:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContextFactory>();
```

Then use it in controller:

```
public class Controller
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
    public Controller(DbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public string Endpoint(string apiParameter)
    {
        using (var context = _dbContextFactory.Create(apiParameter))
        {
            // use context here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to pass *different* connection strings for each request based on some criteria. You should delete this since you already posted a relevant answer

Answer (score -1):

```
//// one of safest way as DbContext is not thread safe 
    List<Model> Items;
    await using (var _dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString:"connection String"))
    {
      Boughts = await _dataContext.YourModel.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You will need two DbContexts.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars {get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motorcycle> Motorcycles { get; set; }
}

public class MyFirstContext : MyContext
{

}

public class MySecondContext : MyContext
{

}
```

And then you can register them like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyFirstContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstConnection")));

    services.AddDbContext<MySecondContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondConnection")));
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: > You're supposed to need two DbContexts, huh? What do you mean by this?

Comment: No, you don't _need_ two different DbContext classes to use different connection strings. It is _a_ solution, but far from the best.

Comment: If you can do it then do it and help him.